# Secure Webhook of Git Repository

Tags: azure

I have a webhook in git Repository and that is connected Azure functions and I want to secure my webhook is there a way that I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In your function app `index.js` file you need to add `crypto-js` library.*

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');
```

*Then copy the function keys from the function app*

[image]

*Now copy and paste the function key in git repository under settings in webhook add key.*

[image]

for more information you can refer the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/monitor-github-events-with-a-function-triggered-by-a-webhook/8-secure-webhook-payloads-with-secret).